# Get link from input using regexp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I need to extract `editpost.php?tid=81432&amp;pid=1557437` from this input blow

```
<input value="Edit" onclick="QuickEditPost('post_message_1557437','81432','editpost.php?tid=81432&amp;pid=1557437');bookmarkscroll.scrollTo('post_message_1557437');" type="button">
```

And add the value to `<a>` tag by **JavaScript or jQuery**

I'm using this code in Google Chrome extension

so the final result will be like this for every input in the page

```
<input value="Edit" onclick="QuickEditPost('post_message_1557437','81432','editpost.php?tid=81432&amp;pid=1557437');bookmarkscroll.scrollTo('post_message_1557437');" type="button">

<a href="editpost.php?tid=81432&amp;pid=1557437">Edit</a>
```

code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/xHZ99/

the result i need http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/xHZ99/1/

Comment: Do you have the HTML as a string or as a DOM object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
var htmlAsString = document.body.innerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML = htmlAsString.replace(
    /QuickEditPost\('post_message_(\d+)','(\d+)'[^>]*>/g,
    function (n0, n1, n2) {
        return n0 +
            '<a href="editpost.php?tid=' + n2 + '&amp;pid=' + n1 + '">Edit</a>';
    }
);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgaNh/)

Note however that parsing HTML by regular expressions is not normally a good idea unless you are in control of the input.